# Is the co-vector space the transpose of the basis of a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

From what I understand, if you have a vector space with bases $ \vec{e_1} , \vec{e_2}$ , you can define a co-vector space with basis $ \vec{a}$ and $ \vec{b}$ such that

$ \vec{a} ( \vec{e_1} ) =  1$
$ \vec{a} ( \vec{e_2} ) =  0$
$ \vec{b} ( \vec{e_1} ) =0$
$ \vec{b} ( \vec{e_2} ) = 1$

Now, this is just like taking the column vector in the original vector space and turning it into a row vector by transposing to get vector in dual basis. By this logic if I transpose back, I would get my vector basis. So does this mean that for all basis, the dual's transpose is the original vector basis? As in their connection is in mainly of transpose operations?

Comment: Vector space and it's Co Co vector space are different things.  You mean isomorfic if they are?

Comment: Why should they be different? Why are they different?